# Python list of tuples how to plot all the tuples with the same key

Tags: python, plot, tuples

In my code, at each iteration step I get a list of tuples that contain a worker_id and a value, like this:

```
[('worker-159', 1.1685709120273498), ('worker-156', 0.7916160785059027), ('worker-150', 1.1486401201147178), ('worker-153', 0.6132945731919339)]
[('worker-159', 1.195049722870496), ('worker-156', 1.0330889397508607), ('worker-150', 1.1598074339882078), ('worker-153', 1.0162635831405047)]
[('worker-159', 1.2002260342341922), ('worker-156', 1.044212019411522), ('worker-150', 1.1610147533213582), ('worker-153', 1.0155351093960254)]
[('worker-159', 1.201086564448113), ('worker-156', 1.0452712882782897), ('worker-150', 1.1611455202975516), ('worker-153', 1.0102820381745612)]
[('worker-159', 1.20145397632951), ('worker-156', 1.0455816259596025), ('worker-150', 1.1611884914303927), ('worker-153', 1.0068296997277124)
[('worker-159', 1.2024538250404766), ('worker-156', 1.0461755869603413), ('worker-150', 1.1612801087850406), ('worker-153', 0.9958443656576963)]
```

I want to plot how each value changes in each step for every worker. So, I want to make 4 plots (one for each worker), where each one has at x-axis the iteration step and at y-axis their corresponding value.

Does anyone have a clue how to do this? I tried to use the method zip, but it only plots the different tuples within the list. ie:

```
        x, y= zip(*res)
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()
```

Gives me one plot for every step with all the worker_ids in x-axis and all their values in y-axis.

I want one plot for every worker_id, the iteration step in the x-axis and his value in y-axis.

I guess it's a matter of how to group the first tuples and then the 2nd tuples etc, based on their key (which is worker_id). But i don't know how to do that.

Comment: must be honest, without seeing the code, can't be of any help. can you post your current code?

Comment: there is no code for this part, just the list i provided in the description, and the task i want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
steps = [[('worker-159', 1.1685709120273498), ('worker-156', 0.7916160785059027), ('worker-150', 1.1486401201147178), ('worker-153', 0.6132945731919339)],
[('worker-159', 1.195049722870496), ('worker-156', 1.0330889397508607), ('worker-150', 1.1598074339882078), ('worker-153', 1.0162635831405047)],
[('worker-159', 1.2002260342341922), ('worker-156', 1.044212019411522), ('worker-150', 1.1610147533213582), ('worker-153', 1.0155351093960254)],
[('worker-159', 1.201086564448113), ('worker-156', 1.0452712882782897), ('worker-150', 1.1611455202975516), ('worker-153', 1.0102820381745612)],
[('worker-159', 1.20145397632951), ('worker-156', 1.0455816259596025), ('worker-150', 1.1611884914303927), ('worker-153', 1.0068296997277124)],
[('worker-159', 1.2024538250404766), ('worker-156', 1.0461755869603413), ('worker-150', 1.1612801087850406), ('worker-153', 0.9958443656576963)]]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax = ax.ravel() #all subaxes in single numpy array, to easily iterate over
ls = len(steps)
for j, ax_sub in enumerate(ax):
    ax_sub.plot(range(ls), [k[j][1] for k in steps])

plt.show()
```

This is just one way. You can also plot them separately in their own figures.

Comment: Ι get this error when I try it : `ax_sub.plot(range(ls), [k[j][1] for k in res]) IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable`. That is because you say steps is a list of lists, but in my case it's not. In every step i get a new list of tuples, and I want to plot the tuples that have the same key.